# How to set state of an object in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I would like to know, which is the correct method to set state of an object in ReactJS.

Please find my sample code:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.updateName = this.updateName.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name: "Sample code"
    };
  }
  updateName() {
    this.setState(name: "Updated");
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateName();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{this.state.name}</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my sample code to update name. Here, name is updated using `setState` and results in the output 'Updated'.

If `updateName()` is rewritten as,

```
updateName(){
  this.state.name = 'Updated';
}
```

and then printing the name, it gives the same result.
I would like to know, the correct method to set the state of an object in ReactJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not mutate the state object directly by assigning a new value to `this.state.name`. You should use the `setState` method and give it an object that should update the state.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.updateName = this.updateName.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      name: "Sample code"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.updateName();
  }

  updateName() {
    this.setState({ name: "Updated" });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <label>{this.state.name}</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to update the state is with this.setState function.

```
updateName() {
   this.setState(oldState, {...oldState, name: "new name"});
}
```

ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html